# CKeditor and TinyMCE output HTML tags on published content

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, tinymce

I know that this is an old one because I've searched the web for 3 hours now and I just can't figure this one out. I know that somewhere in my code I have to put `html_entity_decode` or `htmlspecialchars_decode` because I believe that the html entities aren't converting back when pulled from the database...but where? It doesn't matter whether it's edit or create...and I tried to use both CKeditor and TinyMce..same thing happens..without plugins..so whitout any changes made on the editors..

Here's edit

```
  <?php find_selected_page(); ?>  

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Process the form

$id = $current_subject["id"];
$menu_name = mysql_prep($_POST["menu_name"]);
$position = (int) $_POST["position"];
$visible = (int) $_POST["visible"];
$content = mysql_prep($_POST["content"]);

// validations
$required_fields = array("menu_name", "position", "visible", "content");
validate_presences($required_fields);

$fields_with_max_lengths = array("menu_name" => 30);
validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths);

if (empty($errors)) {

 // Perform Update

$query  = "UPDATE subjects SET ";
$query .= "menu_name = '{$menu_name}', ";
$query .= "position = {$position}, ";
$query .= "visible = {$visible}, ";
$query .= "content = '{$content}' ";
$query .= "WHERE id = {$id} ";
$query .= "LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) {
    // Success
    $_SESSION["message"] = "Stranica uređena.";
    redirect_to("manage_content.php?subject={$id}");
} else {
    // Failure
    $_SESSION["message"] = "Uređivanje stranice neuspjelo.";
}

}
} else {
    // This is probably a GET request

} // end: if (isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
```

Here's where it's echoed

```
<textarea name="content" id="editor1" class="form-control" rows="20" cols="80"><?php echo htmlentities($current_subject["content"]); ?></textarea>
                                       <script>

                                        // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                                        // instance, using default configuration.
                                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                                                language: 'hr',                                                                                                                         

                                            } );
                                      </script>
```

Here are the functions

```
function find_all_subjects($public=true) {
    global $connection; 

    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM subjects ";
    if($public) {
        $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
    }       
    $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC"; 
    $subject_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($subject_set);
    return $subject_set;
}
function find_subject_by_id($subject_id, $public=true) {
    global $connection; 

    $safe_subject_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $subject_id);

    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM subjects ";
    $query .= "WHERE id = {$safe_subject_id} ";
    if($public){
        $query .= "AND visible = 1 ";
    }
    $query .= "LIMIT 1"; 
    $subject_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    //Test if there was a query error
    confirm_query($subject_set);
    if($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)) {
    return $subject;
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}

function find_selected_page($public=false) {
    global $current_subject;
    global $current_page;

    if(isset($_GET["subject"])) {

        $current_subject = find_subject_by_id($_GET["subject"], $public); 
        $current_page = null;
    }elseif (isset($_GET["page"])) {

        $current_page = find_page_by_id($_GET["page"], $public); 
        $current_subject = null;
    }else{

        $current_subject = null;
        $current_page = null;
    }

}
```

So, at the end it should look like this:
Here is **some** text on the public page

Instead it looks like this

```
<p>Here is <strong>some</strong> text on the public page</p>
```

Is there anything else to add here from the code you need to see?

Any suggestions?

Is it possible to display the echoed text raw and then the editor takes it and displays it without the html tags?

Or how can I use this?

[PHP’s strip_tags() equivalent MYSQL function](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/phps-strip-tags-equivalent-mysql-function/5817/2)

If i add

```
    $content = mysql_prep(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($_POST["content"])));
```

then there's no text formatting..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it...turns out I was looking at the wrong thing...I was looking at the "edit page" and fiddled there a lot but i just had to apply html_entity_decode where the content had been shown to the client side or in my case also in "manage content"... an I didn't even include that part in the question...so stupid... :D

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode($current_subject["content"]); ?>
```

maybe this will help someone in the future... :)